# 「Exception: 無効な引数: parent.mimeTypeのException: 無効な引数: parent.mimeType」の解決方法

Tags: google-apps-script

下記のエラーが解決できないです。
ご教示の程よろしくお願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Exception: 無効な引数: parent.mimeType
```

**ソースコード**

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(getid);
  var url    = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ getid +'/export?';
  var opts   = {
    exportFormat: 'xlsx',     // ファイル形式の指定 pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    format:       'xlsx',     // ファイル形式の指定 pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    size:         'A4',      // 用紙サイズの指定 legal / letter / A4
    portrait:     'true',    // true → 縦向き、false → 横向き
    fitw:         'true',    // 幅を用紙に合わせるか
  　sheetnames:   'false',   // シート名を PDF 上部に表示するか
    printtitle:   'false',   // スプレッドシート名を PDF 上部に表示するか
    pagenumbers:  'false',   // ページ番号の有無
    gridlines:    'false',   // グリッドラインの表示有無
    fzr:          'false'  // 固定行の表示有無
    //range :       'A1%3AA1', // 対象範囲「%3A」 = :, A1:A1  
    //gid:           shId      // シート ID を指定 (指定のない場合、スプレッドシート全体をダウンロード)
  };

　 var urlExt = [];
  for(optName in opts){
    urlExt.push(optName + '=' + opts[optName]);
  }

  var options  = urlExt.join('&');
  var token    = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + options, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  });

  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss + '.xlsx');
  Logger.log(blob.getContentType());
  folder.createFile(blob);
    
  }
```

Comment: そのエラーメッセージの前後に他に情報はありませんか？

Comment: スクリプトを見ますと`var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(getid);`と`var url    = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ getid +'/export?';`で同じ`getid`が使用されています。もしもこの`getid`の値がSpreadsheet IDの場合、`var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(getid);`によって、エラーが`folder.createFile(blob);`で発生すると思われます。これがエラーの原因と思われます。例えば、`var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(getid);`を、`var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();`に修正して再度実行すると、他の場所で問題が無ければルートフォルダにXLSXファイルが作成されると思われますが、いかがでしょうか。